# how to execute script without installing the exe of its program

Tags: vb.net, automation, autoit

I am executing a autoit script when autoit is installed in the system by using the following code

```
objProcess = New System.Diagnostics.Process()
objProcess.StartInfo.Arguments = "abc"
objProcess.StartInfo.FileName = "Z:\Scripts\test.au3"
objProcess.Start()
```

But I need to do same by giving a path to a unzipped files instead of installing it on system. Any idea how can I do this.
e.g My autoit path where I extracted files are z:\Software\autoit3.exe and my scripts path is "Z:\Scripts\test.au3".

Comment: I don't understand the question maybe you can try to rephrase? What are you trying to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can compile your script files with the included Au2Exe compiler. This will turn your .au3 files into .exe files and they can be run without needing to install AutoIt on the computer first.

Answer (score 1):

Use the command line parameters as described in the helpfile, and run the autoit3.exe as the main process.

At it's most basic you would use something like:

```
objProcess.StartInfo.FileName = "path\\autoit3.exe"
objProcess.StartInfo.Arguments = "\"path\\test.au3\" abc" // You can add any arguments for the script afterwards.
```

Note that I have never used vb.net, so don't expect anything I write to work first time :P But that is the basic idea.